# Adding forms and input checkboxes dynamically to HTML issue

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, checkbox

I am trying to add forms and input checkboxes dynamically. Below is the Javascript code. I want some html before each checkbox so that user knows what that checkbox is for. This code adds all the description of the checkboxes first and then all the checkboxes. Any idea how can I rectify this?

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.menu_item.modifier_groups.length; i++) {
    var div = document.getElementById("modifiers");
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    var chr = i.toString();
    chr = "form".concat(chr);
    form.setAttribute("name", chr);
    form.setAttribute("id", chr);
    form.modifier_group_name = obj.menu_item.modifier_groups[i].modifier_group_name;
    form.min_modifier_selection = obj.menu_item.modifier_groups[i].min_modifier_selection;
    form.max_modifier_selection = obj.menu_item.modifier_groups[i].max_modifier_selection;
    document.getElementById("modifiers").innerHTML += "<br><br>" + obj.menu_item.modifier_groups[i].modifier_group_name + ":<br>";
    for (var j = 0; j < obj.menu_item.modifier_groups[i].modifiers.length; j++) {
        document.getElementById("modifiers").innerHTML += obj.menu_item.modifier_groups[i].modifiers[j].modifier_name;
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        input.setAttribute("value", obj.menu_item.modifier_groups[i].modifiers[j].modifier_id)
        input.modifier_id = obj.menu_item.modifier_groups[i].modifiers[j].modifier_id;
        input.modifier_name = obj.menu_item.modifier_groups[i].modifiers[j].modifier_name;
        input.is_default = obj.menu_item.modifier_groups[i].modifiers[j].is_default;
        if (input.is_default == true) input.setAttribute("checked", true);
        form.appendChild(input);
    }
    div.appendChild(form);
}
```

Comment: Try instead of using `innerHTML+=someString;`, use `form.appendChild(new Text(someString);`.

Comment: Tried. Doesn't work. gives error

Comment: What is error description?

Comment: This worked: form.appendChild(document.createTextNode("text"));

Comment: Then you should answer your own question.  Or let me answer with your solution.

Comment: Go ahead. Do the honours :). You gave me the direction anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.innerHTML` and `.appendChild()` interchangeably can cause ordering problems like the one you're decribing.  Instead of adding to the element's innerHTML using `innerHTML+=text`, append a new text node using `form.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text)`.

So, replace this line:

```
document.getElementById("modifiers").innerHTML += obj.menu_item.modifier_groups[i].modifiers[j].modifier_name;
```

with this:

```
form.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj.menu_item.modifier_groups[i].modifiers[j].modifier_name));
```